# Protractor for both angular and non angular

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am new to Protractor. I am using Protractor to test both Angular and Non-Angular applications. My testing sequence would be

1. Testing Non-Angular log-in pange
2. Once logged in, Testing Angular Home Page.

I tried the below scripts but it throws me an error.

**Config.js**

```
exports.config = {

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

capabilities: {

    'browserName': 'firefox'
  },
  specs: ['spec1.js'],
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true
  }
};
```

**Spec1.js**

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  it('Availity', function() {

    browser.driver.get('https://qa-apps.availity.com/availity/web/public.elegant.login');

    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('userId')).sendKeys('xxxx');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('password')).sendKeys('yyyy');

    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('loginFormSubmit')).click();

browser.driver.sleep(1);
browser.waitForAngular();

element(by.className('navbar-brand-availity')).click();


  });
});
```

Any help on above issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry.. Forgot to metion the Error details. Here it is...Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.an
gular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or
because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Prot
ractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details

Answer (score 2):

You have to have the sync off when you are working with the non-angular part and then, turn the sync on again after you are logged in. Something like:

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  beforeEach(function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    browser.driver.get('https://qa-apps.availity.com/availity/web/public.elegant.login');

    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('userId')).sendKeys('xxxx');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('password')).sendKeys('yyyy');

    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('loginFormSubmit')).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(1);

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    browser.waitForAngular();
  });

  it('Availity', function() {
      element(by.className('navbar-brand-availity')).click();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do login in your protractor configuration file (config.js), with the `onPrepare` function e.g.

```
exports.config = {
    onPrepare: function () {

        browser.baseUrl = browser.params.baseUrl;
        browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl + 'Account/Login');

        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('UserName')).sendKeys('username');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Password')).sendKeys('PASSWORD');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Login')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);

        return browser.driver.wait(function () {
            return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
                return /home/.test(url);
            });
        }, 90000);
    },
};
```